# Netbeans 6.9.1 and Scala Kit

Tags: scala, netbeans, installation

Has anyone had success installing the Scala plugin into Netbeans recently? I tried to install and when Netbeans restarts, I receive a whole bunch of warnings like:

```
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: had to upgrade dependencies for module org.netbeans.modules.cnd.asm: added = [module org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting/0 > 1.0] removed = []; details: [The old editor formatting API have been deprecated, see http://wiki.netbeans.org/EditorFormattingAPIUpgrade and update your module.]'
```

and then a lot of errors similar to:

```
Warning - could not install some modules: org.netbeans.modules.print.editor - The module named org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib/2 was needed and not found.
```

finally (the one the breaks the back):

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enabled: org.netbeans.modules.editor.lib2` (Netbeans fails to start)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm happily using Netbeans 6.9.1 with **[nb-scala-6.9v1.1.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlybird/files/nb-scala/6.9v1.1.0/nb-scala-6.9v1.1.0.zip/download)**. Which version of plugin are you trying to install? Try to remove the plugin, and reinstall.

Comment: I just installed the plugin last night on 6.8 (and through that experience learned more about how the plugin was trying to work). I think just the practice of getting all the pieces installed helped me on the third or fourth iteration of installing nb-scala plugin on 6.9.1. Thanks for responding!